Web novel with a female lead with red hair who is running away from her husband after finding out his real identity
She stole from a very powerful man and he put a hit on her. He tells her he's someone else and he marries her to keep an eye on her and kill her himself. He ends up falling for her, but she has found out who he really is by then. By the time he realizes he loves her, she was gone.
She was on a business trip to the capital and didn't come back. She was a former Royal Knight with powers to make illustrations and her husband was the only one her powers didn't work on. He is some kind of big bad evil guy. She was there to help her old friends with training someone to take her place as a Knight; with her set of powers, it was rare. She met her friend — I think her name was Ann — and planned the escape together.
It was a fantasy and I think an isekai, but I'm not sure about that part. She had red hair and I think her name was Hazel and last name was something Love. The male lead had black hair and red eyes I think his fake name was Noah the one he told her.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?

I'm not sure after I think chapter 30 it would say something like "we moved sites" and would open a new tap with the next chapter but I had to keep going back and forth which is why I can't find it
